# mailstats not working with sendmail

Tags: sendmail, linux

I am getting following error while trying to use mailstats command

mailstats version (3) incompatible with /etc/mail/statistics version (4).

Can anyone please advise how i can overcome this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that someone installed (a newer) sendmail from source code which was later overwritten by an  operating system patch which installed an older one by the system vendor.  You have two choices:

- As root `cp /dev/null mailstats` so that you can start measuring again
- Install the lastest sendmail from source